# iframe not support by any browser

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe, django-rest-framework

I am getting this error in my console tab

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options: “DENY” from
>   “http://localhost:8000/media/song/bensound-betterdays.mp3”, site does
>   not permit any framing. Attempted to load into
>   “http://localhost:3000/home”.

I also followed this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) to solve this problem, but it didn't help.

api-data:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "song": "http://localhost:8000/media/song/bensound-betterdays.mp3",

    },
]
```

settings.py

```
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
]
```

./src/Home.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

class App extends Component{


    constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    this.state = {
      response: "",
    };

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }


  fetchData = async () => {

    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:8000/api/music`
      );
      const JsonResponse = await response.json();
      this.setState({ response: JsonResponse });
    } 
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };


    render(){

        const { response } = this.state;

         if (!response) {
          return "Loading...";
        }

        return(

                     <div class="home">

                         {response.map((response) =>(

                            <div class="home_content">
                                <div class="track track_home">
                                    <iframe width="100%" height="166" src={response.song}></iframe>
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            ))}

                        </div>

            )
    }
}

export default App;
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: _What_ do you have running/serving content under `http://localhost:8000`? That is the part here that needs to allow framing, not your react app running under `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: The error message is clear enough. The URL you are loading is forbidding you from putting it in a frame. It's localhost, so you should be able to change that. We can't help though. You've not shown us the code which sets that header.

Comment: @CBroe  api data coming under `http://localhost:8000`

Comment: @bounty — And your edit includes some more code which doesn't set that header so ‍♂️

Comment: I am not talking about your API endpoint directly, but about whatever is serving the response when you request `http://localhost:8000/media/song/bensound-betterdays.mp3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change **settings.py** as:

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'http://localhost:8000'
```